# Mongodb (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB does not start. I am using Graylog. I dont know what happens but I have made a fresh install and after few days it just does not start. Both times the error is same

```
@graylog:/etc$ sudo service mongodb status
● mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Tue 2023-02-14 15:45:04 PKT; 1s ago
       Docs: man:mongod(1)
    Process: 204631 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --unixSocketPrefix=${SOCKETPATH} --config ${CONF} $DAEMON_OPTS (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
   Main PID: 204631 (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)

فروری 14 15:45:02 graylog systemd[1]: Started An object/document-oriented database.
فروری 14 15:45:04 graylog systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
فروری
```

I have checked the permissions and they are the correct. I have checked the permissions of the following:

```
/etc/mongodb.conf
/var/log/mongdb
/var/lib/mongodb
```

I have enough space in the drive, almost 6TB free.

I have checked the logs and found this error `2023-02-14T15:53:47.700+0500 E STORAGE [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1676372027:700199][204844:0x7f8058b16ac0], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: read checksum error for 32768B block at offset 16384: block header checksum of 4113582198 doesn't match expected checksum of 2753610840`

Can anyone please guide? I am not able to find any help. I dont want to re-install, as it will destroy all the data

Comment: I’ve added the comment about logs to your original question.

Comment: Reads like a bad hard drive.